# Using the Google Drive API in a Unity project that uses Firebase Auth

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-drive-api

I'm working on an iOS/Android app developed in Unity, that uses Google Sign-in through Firebase Auth, and from what I've read [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#android), that should handle the OAuth 2.0 protocol. I would like to use the Google Drive API to allow the user to load files they have stored in their Drive, but I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to do that in Unity.

The most useful pieces of information are the following GitHub repo and Gist:

- [Unity Package for Google Drive API](https://github.com/Elringus/UnityGoogleDrive)
- [Using Firebase to Authenticate to Google Drive](https://gist.github.com/jamestalmage/2d8d1d5c42157caf349e) (but not specific to Unity)

Any help on how to do it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I ended up using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-5ZtjCP3r8) to implement Google Sign-in through Firebase in Unity. It was very detailed both on how to set up things from the Firebase side as well as Unity.

As for loading files from Drive, the solution was to use [this unity package](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker) that allows you to call the native file picker for each platform, being able to load files from all Drive accounts the user logged-in in his/her phone, as well as any other file provider they could have (the phone storage itself, Dropbox...), all in a UI that is familiar to the user. I leave [here](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery/issues/129#issuecomment-664175603) the issue that led said solution, on another package from the same creator, which, by the way, I have a lot to thank for.